# Response Code 202, Not a Qualified Error Code

Tags: python

I'm working with an API which I post files to. However, when I receive the response, the HTTP status code is a 202. This is to be expected, but in addition the API will also respond with XML content.

So in my try/except block urllib2.urlopen will result in a raised urllib2.HTTPError and destroying the XML content.

```
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError, http_e:
    if http_e.code == 202:
        print 'accepted!'
        pass

print response.read() # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment
```

How can I expect the 202 and keep the response content, but not raise an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

Being silly, I forgot to inspect the exception that is returned by urllib2. It features all of the properties I've been waxing on about for httplib. This should do the trick for you:

```
try:
    urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print "Response code",e.code # prints 404
    print "Response body",e.read() # prints the body of the response...
                                   # ie: your XML
    print "Headers",e.headers.headers
```

**Original**

In this case, given that you're using HTTP as your transport protocol, you'll probably have more luck with the [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) library:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.stackoverflow.com")
>>> conn.request("GET", "/dlkfjadslkfjdslkfjd.html")
>>> r = conn.getresponse()
>>> r.status
301
>>> r.reason
'Moved Permanently'
>>> r.read()
'<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>\n<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>
 This document may be found   
 <a HREF="http://stackoverflow.com/dlkfjadslkfjdslkfjd.html">here</a></body>'
```

You can further use `r.getheaders()` and so forth to inspect other aspects of the response.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I can't use the urllib2.Request class with HTTPConnection.

Comment: You are indeed correct. Is there something particular in the Request class that you're using?

Comment: Yes, byte string, or more accurately, a zip file.